# MsgPack-Java: How to (de)serialize the type of an object (lang.Class<?>)?

Tags: java, serialization, msgpack

Does anyone know how to (de)serialize a class with java types using MsgPack for java (i have had no problem with XML, JSON, Binary, BSON, Hessian and Kryo)?

Example (simplified to better express intent):

```
@Message
public class RequestDTO {

  private Class<?> type;

  public RequestDTO() { }

  public Class<?> getType() {
    return type;
  }

  private void setType(Class<?> type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```